# Slot Availability Schema in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, database-schema

**Question:**

I'm a service provider who can set its availability for the day, the week or the month in the application. Means in advance I can set that I'll be available on these days. As mentioned earlier availability can be set in advance for the day, week & month. What is the best way to store availability of service Provider in **MongoDB**.

Comment: You might want to read [How do I ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), which enhances the probability for getting a useful answer _drastically_. You might find [ESR](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eric_S._Raymond)'s excellent essay [How To Ask Questions The Smart Way](http://catb.org/~esr/faqs/smart-questions.html) helpful.

Comment: @MarkusWMahlberg thanks for suggestion i'll improve it all the way. but i'm in need of quick solution a bit. please help me to find out.